# How to configure Youtube to prefer 720p framerate over 720p50?

Tags: video, youtube

(performance of my device doesn't allow me to watch 720p50, but allows 720p)

youtube-dl says that Youtube has the video in 720p quality, but Youtube website doesn't allow me to pick it. How do I select the framerate on the Youtube website? And how do I set up Youtube to select it automatically for new videos?

```
youtube-dl --list-formats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
[info] Available formats for :
format code  extension  resolution note
140          m4a        audio only tiny  135k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 81.86MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   720p 2368k , avc1.64001f, 25fps, video only, 736.21MiB
298          mp4        1280x720   720p50 3939k , avc1.640020, 50fps, video only, 1.01GiB
22           mp4        1280x720   720p 1292k , avc1.64001F, 25fps, mp4a.40.2@192k (44100Hz) (best)
```

(I know I can download it using `youtube-dl --format 22 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` but I prefer to watch in Youtube)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer I found is to install a tampermonkey userscript "[Disable YouTube 60 FPS (Force 30 FPS)](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/23329-disable-youtube-60-fps-force-30-fps)":

[image: before/after comparison screenshot]

- this works for me. hth!